# Xelatex: The problem of Including pdf file in the book class

Tags: pdfpages

I'm a user of Latex program.

I have a problem of the including pdf file.
originally, it had been worked several times ago, but now, it is not working.
I just added the some texts in this document and then it doesn't work anymore.
Of course, I contain the package "\usepackage{pdfpages}".

The page number is printed but the contents and details of pdf are not printed, just white pages with page number. Besides all the pdf pages are counted correctly.

Could you help me that I can solve this problem?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter*{국제 논문}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{국제 논문}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{inter.pdf}
\cleardoublepage
\chapter*{국내 논문}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{국내 논문}
\includepdf[pages=-, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{dom.pdf}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: Aside, you need `\phantomsection` before `\addcontentsline...`.

Comment: Thanks to your comments. I have the new things to try. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the 'draft' option turned on in the \documentclass ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't use the draft option in document class. But, i just solved my problem though it's not the standard way. I compiled only 'including pdf' code with pdflatex not xelatex. thus, i got the new pdf file from the original and then compiled full text  including pdf with xelatex, which handled by pdflatex compile. I'm a beginner. So i don't know the fundamental latex syntax principle. Maybe some codes were not comtible because without other codes, it looked like as going well.